# How should a mouse-over-for-keyboard-shortcuts be designed?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hover, tooltips, click, toolbar

Our toolbar has a keyboard icon on the right, which, when hovered over, displays a large keyboard reference tooltip. Clicking the icon opens the settings' dialog on the tab for keyboard bindings.

My feeling is that the icon does not intuitively indicate the functionalities. How can we fix this?

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put the whole thing in a settings palette along with other global settings?

Comment: @AndrewMartin What is a *settings palette*?

Comment: The window where the user manages all the settings for the product/system you are designing - often has things like Username and password management, language settings, appearance settings, keyboard shortcut management, etc

Comment: @AndrewMartin Oh, that is in fact already the case. See updated OP. The question here is regarding the hint, not the settings interface.

Comment: The hint screen is a bit much - that's a lot of screen you're obscuring with a hover interaction. Have you considered a hint that simply says "settings and keyboard shortcuts" as a hint to what the button (which should be for settings if that's what it contains) does and let the user explore from there?

Comment: @AndrewMartin Maybe we can remove the two-letter codes, and the non-assigned entries, and let the title read `Keyboard Shortcuts (click to edit)`.

Comment: You're still going to be covering a large area of the screen with a hover interaction - If you want to make it visible over the main screen I would suggest you make it a pull out palette that the user can open and close with a positive click rather than a hover

Comment: @AndrewMartin Nice idea, why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your UI likely should not have a hover interaction or a tooltip for a display this large. It would be benefited by using a click interaction and a modal with scrolling and search. This would allow you to offer all your shortcuts in a non-overwhelming way. I have set up a web demo of a possible implementation of that concept but it uses some modern code and may not run in all browsers (I have tested on latest chrome and edge versions).

The important things to note from the demo are the spacing: which allows easy scanning of the text, the hover effect: which keeps focus to the line at the expected place, and the differentiation between monospace and non-monospace font: which also allows for easier reading.

Many places do this but the best example I can think of is the Atom code editor. They offer a complete search of the keyboard shortcuts and their UI allows for easy scanning. This makes for a pleasant experience for the user.

http://codepen.io/CKH4/pen/PpNKoB/
Please let me know if you need a gif of the functionality in case you aren't able to access the webpage.